# Connecting to remote server failed: The WinRM client cannot process the request

Tags: powershell, remote, winrm

I am trying to execute a powershell script on a remote server from my local machine, however I get an error.
Here is the full error message:

> Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.
> If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the
> destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts
> list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionStateBroken

Now this is a common error and I found lots of information on it already, however none lead to a successful connection. What I have done:

- In an elevated PowerShell window
- Started WinRM on both machines
- Checked the port where the remote machine is listening with:

> winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener

- Added the remote machine to my trusted hosts on the local machine
- All done with administrator privileges
- Both machines are on the same domain

The remote machine is a VM hosted on Azure, but that should not matter. The ports are not getting blocked on the firewall either.

I am really not sure what else to check for right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post result from winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener ?